# Socket only works once

Tags: java, sockets, irc, bots, serversocket

I'm coding a little program that checks an online store for new items in a specific department. When it does find that a new item has been added, it's supposed to send that info to a simple IRC-bot, which in turn writes it out in a channel so I can see it immediately.

The problem is that the IRC part only works once. So while the parser successfully announce every new item at the store in my console, the IRC bot only shows the first. So the problem is most likely my socket code.

I shall tell you that I'm a complete noob with sockets, so it can be a really simple problem(for you, that is).

Enough talk, here's the relevant code:

The bot:

```
public void openSocket() throws IOException{

    serversock = new ServerSocket(1551);
    Socket sock = serversock.accept();

    BufferedReader incoming = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    String inString = incoming.readLine();

    sendMessage("#channel", inString);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XanaduBot bot = new XanaduBot();
    bot.setVerbose(true);

    bot.connect("irc.server.net");
    bot.joinChannel("#channel");

    bot.openSocket();
}
```

And the socket part on the scraper:

```
if(old == false){
    Socket client = new Socket("localhost",1551);
    DataOutputStream toBot = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    String infoToSend = "New product! "+ info;
    toBot.writeBytes(infoToSend + '\n');
    toBot.flush();

    System.out.println(infoToSend);
}
```

The variable old is false whenever the program finds a new item. And I know that exceptions are handled pretty bad here, sorry for that!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You don't have any sort of looping construct in `openSocket` - why are you expecting it _not_ to return after the first message?

Comment: You should definitely learn how byte and character streams work, and how to close them properly. Why are you sending bytes at one end, and receiving chars at the other end? Read the Java IO tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments. Mat: I thought for a while that the socket would stay open to accept more input from the client if I never closed it, that was not the case of course, so my problem was solved with a while loop in openSocket. JB: You're right, I rushed it a bit and mixed up some stuff. I'll read that thoroughly, thank you.